# Is it possible to remove an input's content when it's focused by pressing a key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Is it possible to remove an input's content when it's focused by pressing a key?

Thank you in anticipation! :)

Comment: You know, I just bet it _is_ possible; why don't you try it, and then come back with any issues? We like to help those that help themselves.

Comment: i don't meant pressing backspace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. With jQuery you can do something like the following (see http://jsfiddle.net/5tsNW/1/ for a demo):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="testInp" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#testInp").on("keydown", function (e) {
        // backspace is key code 8
        if(e.keyCode === 8) {
            $(this).val("");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ohh my god, i tried this a couple of times, but now it works :o
thank you, anyway :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('input').keypress(function(event) {
    if ( event.which == 8 ) { // backspace
        $(this).val('');
    }
}
```